# Passing password in session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set the password `textbox` back to the text entered before a `checkbox` is and has `AutuoPostback`.

```
Session["passwordText"] = txt_Password.Text;
```

This is on my pageLoad and then I have tried to add(below) in my `CheckedChanged` but it says Method `Add` has 2 parameters and is invoked with 1 argument? What should i include with `passWord`.

```
var passWord = Session["passwordText"].ToString();

txt_Password.Attributes.Add(passWord);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
txt_Password.Attributes.Add("value", passWord);
```

or why not

`txt_Password.Text = passWord;` ?

Comment: it wouldn't do it with passWord because of TextMode Property just kept it empty.  But it works know .. thank you